# Running out of cards with "Loss of Card" in Sequence

Tags: sequence

Here are the [rules](https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/) of Sequence.

> Loss of Card
>
> Once you have taken your turn and placed your marker chip on the game board, you must take a card from the draw deck. If you fail to take a card before the next player makes a move AND takes his/her card, you lose the right to take a card and you must finish the game with less cards than the other players – a disadvantage.

If a player losses all cards during the course of the game via "Loss of Card", then what should that player do in his/her next turn?

---

*P.S.: I encountered this seemingly unlikely scenario and suggested that the player should draw a card and immediately end his/her turn. The alternative would seem to have that player stop playing altogether.*

Comment: For one, they should pay better attention

Comment: No disagreements there @Veskah

Comment: Are you looking more for an actual, rules based answer as to what you are SUPPOSED to do in this case? Or just wondering what a balanced home rule would be to solve it?

Comment: @CollinB: I'm looking for a rules based answer but I would appreciate your input on a balanced home rule if you have something in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you loose the game since you don't have any cards left and hence no longer are able to follow the rules.

The rules state that when it's your turn you should select a card from your hand and put it on the discard pile. It doesn't say that you are allowed to skip this and just take a card from the draw deck.

> ...each player selects a card of their choice from their hand and places it face up on a discard pile...

But I guess that a house rule allowing you to just draw a card is a good adjustment of the rules. All in favor of being able to finish playing the game.

[SEQUENCE Rules](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53ec790ae4b0396cbd14d8a1/t/5ad4158f352f53c87a470cb6/1523848592053/sequence-board-game-rules.pdf)

Comment: This was my same interpretation of the rules. However, would the player *and* their team lose the game too?

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no rules based solution as to what happens in this scenario. Due to this lack, it seems that the player would simply be unable to play, since they have no cards. Personal house rule recommendation: nothing. Leave it as is. If someone forgets SO MUCH that they lose all of their cards, I think at that point they might deserve to lose. When you have one card, and everyone else has 5 (I think it's 5?) then it seems kind of difficult to forget that you have been losing cards to "Loss of Card," and so, easier to remember to not do it again. A player should be involved in the game enough to not be that oblivious to their turn. If there some sort of issue causing them to not pay attention, consider removing that distraction. An inattentive player is worse than no player in some cases.